# Magento 2 - remove preselection of shipping-address in checkout

Tags: php, magento, templates, knockout.js, magento2

i want to remove the preselection of the shipping-address in the checkout-process. Because on default there's always on selected address selected. It would be great if the next-butotn is also hidden until the customer select one address.

Because everything is loaded via ajax and the handled by ko i'm not very sure where to start. I found the file where the shipping-addresses are loaded but as I said it's somehow handled by ko and I'm not that familiar with it:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/list.html**

```
<!-- ko if: (visible)-->
<div class="field addresses">
    <div class="control">
        <div class="shipping-address-items">
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
            <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Does someone can help me where to start or has a similiar situation?

Comment: The html by itself isn't all that useful. Knockout relies heavily on javascript so you'll want to show the relevant .js file that goes along with the html.

Comment: Inspect inserted item templates and track the code that makes them preselected.